# How to generate uniques after subtracting arrays' elements based on conditions using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to check if the item in `array1` exists in `array2` and, if so, subtract col4 from col5 to output th pending qty. If not, then, item's qty from `array1` is the pending qty.

```
let array1 = 
[
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 10, 0],
 [2, "Item B", "Food", 5, 0],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 30, 0]
]
```

```
let array2 = 
[
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 5, 3],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 10, 5]
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
let res= 
[
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 10, 7],
 [2, "Item B", "Food", 5, 0],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 30, 25]
]
```

I started it using `for` loops, but I was wondering what this would look like using `map()` or `reduce()`?

```js
let array1 = [
  [1, "Item A", "Food", 10, 0],
  [2, "Item B", "Food", 5, 0],
  [3, "Item C", "Food", 30, 0]
]

let array2 = [
  [1, "Item A", "Food", 5, 3],
  [3, "Item C", "Food", 10, 5]
]

let result = [];
for (let a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
  let item = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < array2.length; r++) {
    if (array1[a][0] == array2[r][0] && array1[a][1] == array2[r][1]) {
      let pendingQty = array1[a][3] - array2[r][4];
      if (pendingQty > 0) {
        item = [array1[a][0], array2[r][1], array2[r][2], array2[r][3], pendingQty];
      } else {
        item = array1[a];
      }
    }
    if (item.length === 0) {
      item = array1[a];
    }
  }
  result.push(item.slice());
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why isn't the second row in your expected result `[2, "Item B", "Food", 5, 5]`?

Comment: Time-saving tip: the achieve `inline formatting` in Markdown, you only need single backticks, not three. Three is only required for blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a1 = [ [1, "Item A", "Food", 10, 0], [2, "Item B", "Food", 5, 0], [3, "Item C", "Food", 30, 0]];
let a2 = [ [1, "Item A", "Food", 5, 3], [3, "Item C", "Food", 10, 5]];
console.log(a1.map(e=>[...e.slice(0,4),e[3]-(a2.find(j=>j[1]===e[1])?.[4]??0)]));
```

Comment: Would you mind putting a word  of 2 on this piece ```?.[4]??0)```? Thanks!

Comment: @onit Sure - the `?.` part means that if the `find` operation returns undefined, there will not be an error thrown when you try to access the [4] part of the result of the find. Instead, you'll get `undefined` from the find, and `??0` converts any `undefined` to `0` to indicate there is nothing to subtract.

Comment: @onit btw I just realised I could have used `.slice()` to avoid `e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3]`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: All clear, @AndrewParks! Thanks a lot!